# Can overflow-anchor work on pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css, overflow, pseudo-element

This demo I found online uses the `overflow-anchor` property to keep a div scrolled to the bottom:

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bGbeBdp

I tried to modify it to use the `::after` pseudo-element, but it doesn't seem to work:

https://codepen.io/00gogo00/pen/NWLdKQO

Is there a way to make the latter work, or does the property simply not work outside of a real element?

Comment: It looks like you don't understand the essence of insertBefore(). This thing not only inserts html code above the specified element, but also holds the position of this element. By replacing insertBefore() with append(), you simply add elements to the end of #scroller. If you need automatic scrolling down, then calculate the coordinates of the bottom of the #scroller and use scrollBy().

Comment: So it's not possible to do this without a dummy element or additional JavaScript?